# jQuery single looping an image cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have the following jQuery, which I am very new at, and I am trying to loop 22 images of a painting inside a transparent frame but stop on the last one. I am using the following jQuery code:

```
function swapImages(){
  var $active = jQuery('#frame-gallery .active');
  var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : jQuery('#frame-gallery img:first');
  $active.removeClass('active');
  $next.addClass('active');
}
jQuery(document).ready($startSwap = function(){
  // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
  setInterval('swapImages()', 120);
});
```

I have been at this all day, trying carious places for clearInterval but it will not work...

Comment: The $startSwap function is a remnant of one of my many attempts to do this and forgot to delete it.

Comment: Are you trying to change the picture every 120ms until it reaches the last one then stop? Or are you wanting to loop over all 22 images every 120ms over and over?

Comment: If you're interested in using bootstrap, it's carousel will do this for you. Here's a demo: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_wrap_data&stacked=h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the logic for `$next` a little bit -- only add/remove class if the next node exists. And clear interval if next doesn't exist:

```js
var interval;

function swapImages(){
  var $active = jQuery('#frame-gallery .active');
  
  if ($active.next().length > 0) {
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $active.next().addClass('active');
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready($startSwap = function(){
  // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
  interval = setInterval(swapImages, 300);
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="frame-gallery">
  <li class="active">a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, I had something extremely similar to this except the var interval and the interval = setInterval (etc.) This must be something I messed up on.